# AWS Glue CDK - create job type Spark (Glue 2.0)

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I could not find any documentation on how to create a glue job with the type spark. The way examples and documentation suggests creates type python shell. Example:

```
glueETLJob = _glue.CfnJob(
        self,
        "glue_CDK_job",
        command =_glue.CfnJob.JobCommandProperty(
            name = "glue_CDK_job",
            python_version= '3',
            script_location = bucket + "/code/glue_CDK_job.py"
        ),
        role= glueRole.role_arn,
        max_retries= 0,
        name= "glue_CDK_job",
        timeout=30,
        glue_version="1.0"
    )
```

Creates a python shell with version 1, but I cannot set glue_version="2.0" because that only seems to exist in type Spark.

**Does anyone know how to do create a glue job with type Spark and glue version 2.0 with CDK**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the name in theJobCommandProperty is not a id like others, but the type that I was looking for. So if anybody has the same issue it should look like:

```
glueETLJob = _glue.CfnJob(
    self,
    "glue_CDK_job",
    command =_glue.CfnJob.JobCommandProperty(
        name = "glueetl",
        python_version= '3',
        script_location = bucket + "/code/glue_CDK_job.py"
    ),
    role= glueRole.role_arn,
    max_retries= 0,
    name= "glue_CDK_job",
    timeout=30,
    glue_version="2.0"
)
```

Got the answer from: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4480

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but I realized that the issue was caused by `name` in `JobCommandProperty`. Change `glue_CDK_job` to `glueetl` will be work.

You can check the documentation of AWS Cloud Formation.
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/aws-resource-glue-job.md

Answer (score 0):

```
const processFifaDataJobName = 'process-data-fifa';
const PYTHON_VERSION = "3";
const GLUE_VERSION = "1.0";
const COMMAND_NAME = "glueetl";
const glueJobProcessFifaData = new glue.CfnJob(this, processFifaDataJobName, {
    name: processFifaDataJobName,
    role: role.roleArn,
    command: {
      name: COMMAND_NAME,
      pythonVersion: PYTHON_VERSION,
      scriptLocation: 's3://' + bucketName + '/Scripts/process-data.py'
    },
    glueVersion: GLUE_VERSION
  });
```

For me above code worked. Although it is very similar what you are trying to do. But this created job with type spark.